# Tomcat/TomEE Arguments configuration in Eclipse for JAAS support

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jaas, apache-tomee

I am configuring TomEE to work with JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization Service) and I would like to know if you see something wrong in the following screenshot. I am asking this because I am trying to figure out JAAS configuration troubles that I am experiencing. Troubles that result in an authentication failure in the very simple login page I am trying to manage to work.

**StackOverflow website seems to not allow you to zoom the image, so you should open it by right clicking and "show image" (in Firefox)**
[image: Eclipse Run Configurations]

Comment: "Troubles" is way too generic. Please state clearly what you want to do, what you did to do it and what went wrong. Also, please share any relevant source code and log messages that can help framing the problem.

Comment: I mean if the syntax is correct